# Pass doesn't ask for passphrase

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gnupg, passphrase

I am using pass (http://www.zx2c4.com/projects/password-store/) on ubuntu 12.04.

Process:

```
apt-get install pass
gpg --gen-key
pass init <generated gpg id>
pass insert test
pass test
```

After the last command, this is the output:

```
gpg: gpg-agent is not available in this session
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: Invalid passphrase; please try again ...
gpg: can't query passphrase in batch mode
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available
```

I have searched all over and have yet to find an answer as to why it won't prompt me for a password? I have tested this on three ubuntu 12.04 machines (all with the same error), but when I tested it on mac os 10.9 it prompts me for a passphrase. (This is why I assume the problem is that it isn't prompting for a passphrase).

Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW n a later version of Ubuntu I followed your instructions and it worked.

Comment: Are you aware of http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136182 ? It looks exactly like your issue and suggests setting `GPG="gpg2"` in /usr/bin/pass

Answer (score 0):

syneticon-dj takes the cake! Appending '2' to `GPG="gpg2"` in /usr/bin/pass is a solution.

Thanks!